# GWT History and IE6 / 7

Tags: gwt, history, gwt-history

I've asked this question on the GWT group with no luck, so now I'm trying Stack Overflow :)

There seems to be some problem with GWT's history and IE6 / 7, and I'm trying to confirm this is an actual problem with GWT and not just something stupid I've done.

The problem I run into is the following:

Imagine you have some GWT app that plugs in to your existing website. It has internal history and works fine. Let's just say it's a tree. What it is isn't important, just that it has state that you can go back and forwards in. Part of this app is links to other parts of your website. Click one of those and you exit the GWT application.

Now, use the "back" button after you've clicked one of these links. You return to the GWT application which loads fine and the state is recreated using whatever is in the URL.

If you the click back *again*, here's where I get differing results in IE6 / 7 and FF / Chrome / IE8. In IE6 / 7 this second "back" sends me to the page *before* the GWT app. In FF / Chrome / IE8 this second back sends me back in the *state* of the GWT app, which is what I want, naturally.

I've checked my code, and as far as I can see, this second "back" just goes directly to the page before. My history handler is never called, at any rate.

Has anyone else run into this? Or know of anywhere this problem is discussed? I've googled extensively with no results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GWT group is to noisy to get confirmations of potential bugs, it's mostly for beginners.

The approach I take when I start to assume that there is a bug in GWT, and after trying to get help from the GWT group, is to create an issue in the GWT issue tracker and cross posting in the GWT contributors group as well.

Here is the URL for creating an issue:
http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/list

Make sure that you first search the issue list for possible duplicates.

I've not yet played with history in GWT since our apps are running in an IFrame and that just kills the possibility to implement history.